# libcurl HTTP request to save respond into variable - c++

Tags: c++, httprequest, libcurl

I'm trying to save the returned data from HTTP request into a variable.

The code below will automatically print the respond of the request, but I need it to save the respond to a char or string.

```
int main(void)
{
        char * result;
        CURL *curl;
        CURLcode res;
        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if(curl) {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.browsarity.com/");

            res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        }
        return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you will have to write a function to pass as a write callback via `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` (see [this](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTWRITEFUNCTION)). Alternatively you could create a temporary file and pass its file descriptor via `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` (the next option listed on that page). Then you would read back the data from the temporary file into a string. Not the prettiest of solutions, but at least you don't have to mess with buffers and function pointers.

**EDIT**: Since you don't want to write to a file, something like this might work:

```
#include <string>

size_t write_to_string(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t count, void *stream) {
  ((string*)stream)->append((char*)ptr, 0, size*count);
  return size*count;
}

int main(void) {
  // ...
  if (curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.browsarity.com/");

    string response;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_to_string);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    // The "response" variable should now contain the contents of the HTTP response
  }
  return 0;
}
```

*DISCLAIMER*: I haven't tested this, and I'm a bit rusty on C++, but you can try it out.

Comment: I already was in that link but I couldn't understand how to do that, with the pointers and all.
and the file thing isn't good for me, because I have a small amount of data and I need it to be very fast..

Comment: works for me. i use string* as last parameter type in write_to_string, this saves me a casting.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example for you http://code.google.com/p/aws4c/source/browse/trunk/aws4c.c#637.

T.Yates is right, you have to make a function that will receive the data. And let CURL know about your function using CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.

Comment: can you tell me how to do that with a little more details? like where to put CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION ?

Answer (score 0):

To make the code more understandable, I would have the `write_to_string` function something like this.

```
size_t write_to_string(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, std::string stream)
{
  size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
  std::string temp(static_cast<const char*>(ptr), realsize);
  stream.append(temp);
  return realsize;
}
```

Comment: In this, your `std::string stream` is local to the function, so all of the data would be lost after the function ends...